# Asking user to pick particular type of information that the user wish to be modify (Java File)

Tags: java

Recently I'm trying to make a Customer Relationship Management and I wish to give the user the ability to update their info. Meaning allowing them to edit the specific type of information such as Phone, Name .etc. But however, the user needs to input which filed that they want to update. After fighting for a while, I could not figure out the way to have that ability
Should I use String Buffer or String builder to build this method?
Edit: Sorry about the misinformation, i have linked down the data inside the lead.csv

```
    import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Edit {
    static Scanner x;

public static void editRecord() throws ParseException {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("ENter your ID");
    String ID = scanner.next();
    String name = scanner.next();
    String email = scanner.next();
    String address = scanner.next();
    String date = scanner.nextLine();
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    Date userDate = format.parse(date);
    String gender = scanner.nextLine();
    boolean Gender = Boolean.parseBoolean(gender);
    int phone = scanner.nextInt();

    String filepath = "leads.csv";
String tempfile = "temp.csv";
File oldFile = new File(filepath);
File newFile = new File(tempfile);
String ID1 = ""; String name1 = ""; String phone1 = "";String email1="";String address1 = ""; String userdate1 = "";
String Gender1 = "";
try{
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(tempfile,true);
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(bw);
    x = new Scanner(new File(filepath));
    x.useDelimiter("[,\n]");

    while (x.hasNext()){
        ID1 = x.next();
        name1 = x.next();
        phone1 = x.next();
        email1 = x.next();
        address1 = x.next();
        userdate1 = x.next();
        Gender1 = x.next();
        if(ID1.equals(ID)){
            pw.println(name+","+phone+","+email+","+address+","+userDate+","+Gender);
        }
        else {
            pw.println(name1+","+phone1+","+email1+","+address1+","+userdate1+","+Gender1);
        }
        x.close();
        pw.flush();
        pw.close();
        oldFile.delete();
        File dump = new File(filepath);
        newFile.renameTo(dump);
    }

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    System.out.println("Error Occured");
}


}
```

}

Leads.csv (Data)

```
 0,Jason,pi@gmail.com,15Woodsetn street,01-05-2000,False,015484814
```

Comment: Both are similar. BUT: StringBuffer is threadsafe while StringBuilder isn't. However the processing of  StringBuilder is much faster than StringBuffer.

Comment: @Joe So StringBuffer is safer got it but how to implement them inside the method?